# Java application server without HTTP

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, bytestream

I have a client software that is written in C++/C# and a database. Now I don't want the client to access the database directly, so I thought about placing an application server in the middle. This one should get a short request from the client, ask the database for new data, do some filtering (that can't be done in sql) and then return the data to the client.

My search for this kind of software brought me to Glassfish or Tomcat but my problem in understanding is, that these always want to talk http with html/jsp. Because most of my data is encrypted anyways, I don't need such plain text protocols and would be totally happy with something that just takes a byte stream.
On the other hand would it be nice to have a server handle the thread pool for me (don't want to implement all that from scratch).

After more than a day of searching / testing I'm even more confused than at the beginning (ejb, beans, servlet, websocket, ... so many things to google before understanding just the simplest tutorials).

TL;DR: how do I get Tomcat/Glassfish to just open a socket and create a new thread for every request, without any HTML/CSS/JSP involved?

Comment: If you use restful web services you can pass parameters between client and server.  This is more in line with your planned approach.  A good place to start is with https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/.  Using spring configuration you can setup and configure most of your resources.  There are lots of examples available.

Comment: In short: you dont, unless you massively abuse Tomcat. HTTP is the lowest level protocol Tomcat wants to talk. What's wrong with using HTTP and returning binary data from a servlet?

Comment: You don't need any HTML, CSS, JSP. Write just a simple servlet to query the database and return the result as XML, JSON or plain text. Or reinvent the wheel and write your own protocol. But then you don't need an application server at all. A simple byte stream is not enough. You need to pass some parameters and return the results in a structured format that your client understand. So at least you have to implement some basic kind of protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty and Tomcat are so called servlet container and thus primarly targeted at HTTP exchanges. Glassfish is an application server that uses a servlet container as one of its modules. I would stop thinking in that direction - that's all more like web applications and web services - some levels too high what you are asking for.

I think you should more look into sth. like [Netty](http://netty.io) which is merley a "high performance protocol" server. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html) (even some sort of tutorial there which might fit your use case).

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish is an "enterprise application server", targeting the Java EJB specification. That's surely overdone for your purpose. You can give Tomcat a try. It is a "servlet container", targeting Java Servlet specification. Servlets have one purpose: listening to an incoming URL (request), executing Java code and returning a response, usually over HTTP.

For sure, you may start your own (plain) [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html), for example using a [ServletContextListener](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) (which will be started once your application starts). But you should go for a higher protocol to send the data, like [Hessian and Burlap](http://hessian.caucho.com/), which is implemented in both, Java and C++ and [easy to set up](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/examples/hessian-add/).